# how to insert value to a global variable in fetch api then on success

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am using fetch api inside a function so in success response i want to insert the value into a global variable but it is not doing this.

example code is

```
function getExcludeDates(){

 var data; 

 fetch('/get-exclude-dates')
 .then(res => res.text())
 .then(text => {
    data = text.data;
    //$('#students_count_reservation').prop('disabled', true);
 });

return data;
}
```

return data shows undefined in console log

Comment: res.text() or res.json()

Comment: ☝️ None of this will make any difference. The answer is simply: *you can't.*

Comment: What do you mean by return data? `res.text` or the `data`? I feel the `return data` should move insde the async call (second `then`)

Comment: @CRayen you can't return out of a synchronous function from a callback.

Comment: res.text is an array and whatever i write whether res.json or res.text no matter i just want to put the value of result in a variable which i can return as callback result

Comment: Again, You. Can. Not. You want to `return fetch(...).then(...)` to return *a promise* from `getExcludeDates`, and then in the caller you will need to asynchronously handle the promise. You cannot synchronously return the value immediately, because it doesn't exist immediately.

Comment: After your advice i am doing this and getting result without fetch api

async function getExcludeDates(){
  
 var data = await getdates()

 return data;
}


function getdates(){

  return new Promise(resolve => {
       resolve(text.data);
  });

 
}

but i am not getting any result when i put fetch api inside resolve obj

Comment: @deceze thanks for suggestion please submit your answer i will accept that .. you were right, intead of res.text() i had to use res.json() and i got the value from promise obj